# MARS : How to fit a time series with Earth package and find knots in R

Tags: r

We are working on a univariate time series data.

How can we fit a mars model with earth package ? I think I was able to do the same.
After fitting how to find knots in the fitted model.

Please find the code we are using

```
library(tsoutliers)
library(expsmooth)
library(fma)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
library(earth)

setwd("./files/")
examples <- list.files("./")
print(examples)
length(examples)

labels <- c('Raw', 'Smoothed', 'second time smoothed')
cols <- c('red', 'yellow', 'blue')
par(new=TRUE)
for (i in c(2:10)){ # length(examples)
  # par(mfrow=2:1)
  dataseries <- read.csv(examples[i])
  series <- ts(dataseries[2], start = 1, end = length(dataseries[,2]),na.omit(daily_data$cnt_ma), frequency = 1)
  plot(series, col = cols[1], main=examples[i])
  smoothedseries <- filter(series, filter=rep(1/140, 140),
                           method= 'convolution', sides=2)
  lines(smoothedseries, col=cols[2], lwd=2)

  second <- filter(smoothedseries, filter=rep(1/140, 140),
                   method= 'convolution', sides=2)
  lines(second, col=cols[3], lwd=2)
  legend("bottomleft", labels, col=cols, lwd=2)
  df <- data.frame(smoothedseries)
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
  df1 <- cbind(dataseries[1], df)
  mars <-  earth(x = df1[2], y = df1[1])
  plot(mars)
  #plot.earth.models(mars)
  #earth_plotmodsel(mars)
  #print(mars$grsq)
  # cp <- ts(dataseries[4], start = 1, end = length(dataseries[,4]),na.omit(daily_data$cnt_ma), frequency = 1)
  # plot(cp,  main=examples[i])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find knots from MARS fit. By using model$cuts[model$selected_cuts] parameters